# Share a URL that is shareable on Facebook on LinkedIn

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, sharing

I've worked on sharing dynamic content to be shareable on Facebook populating OpenGraph tags, I know LinkedIn uses OpenGraph tags.

To my surprise when I've tried sharing the same url on LinkedIn nothing shows up.

did anyone have such experience?

I've used https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

But no luck, I get '503 Failure' exception.

Is this the new way to share something on LinkedIn? (Below url)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin

I've tried inspecting the url with https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

also

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
Here in facebook I got response for all the og:tags

Answer (score 0):

I've update the URL-rewrite on ISS to allow UserAgent: LinkedInBot, this change allowed to LinkedIn crawler retrieve the og tags to be populated for linked in crawler request.